# Character set for price

Tags: ios

This is part of the code to retrieve the price from store.

```
NSNumberFormatter * priceFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[priceFormatter setLocale:_skProduct.priceLocale];
NSString *price = [priceFormatter stringFromNumber:_skProduct.price];
```

The resulting price has to be presented using bitmap font in Cocos2D, because design effect should be applied on it. The question is - what is the full set of characters which required in order to display price in all possible locales. Then I will put the set into GlyphDesigner and export font. I can't put all unicode characters since the atlas size is limited, so I need only the set for displaying price (digits, dollar, euro sign, maybe some latin letters..).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a list of countries where your in app purchase is available.
2. Turn that list into an NSArray of locale identifiers.
3. Iterate over that array and create a NSLocale
4. Use this locale to create a price string with a NSNumberFormatter
5. Save all the characters you have used.
6. ???
7. Profit

Something like this should do it:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];

// all available locales, you probably don't need them all
NSArray *availableLocaleIdentifiers = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];            

// compile a list of the locales you'll need
availableLocaleIdentifiers = @[ @"de_DE", @"de_CH", @"en_GB", @"en_US", @"ja_JP"];   
for (NSString *localeIdentifier in availableLocaleIdentifiers) {
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:localeIdentifier];
    nf.locale = locale;
    NSString *priceString = [nf stringFromNumber:@(123456789.99)];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [priceString length]; i++) {
        unichar character = [priceString characterAtIndex:i];
        [set addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", character]];
    }
}
NSArray *sorted = [set sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"description" ascending:YES]]];
NSString *allCharacters = [sorted componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"\"%@\"", allCharacters);
```

output: `"$',.0123456789CFH £€￥"`

Comment: You could simply the accumulation of the necessary characters quite a bit with an `NSMutableCharacterSet`. See especially its method `-addCharactersInString:`. This method might also be of some interest: `+[NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes]`

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way to get out all the characters in a characterSet. That'll make the for loop easier, but after you created the NSCharacterSet you have to make another loop to test the full range of UTF8-characters and figure out if it's part of the characterSet.

Comment: and an additional note because I forgot it before: Since this code is not supposed to run in the final app, performance does not matter at all.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right. My apologies! (And, no, performance certainly doesn't matter for something meant to run offline; I just meant to point out for the record that there are framework classes that handle this kind of task.)